# Zend Framework: Can I set a View variable within a model?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

In my controller, I usually do:

```
$this->view->foo = "bar";
```

(I call this vars, as VIEW-VARS)

In view script, I render this with:

```
echo $this->foo;
```

So, I wonder if it's possible to define "view vars" inside models(not in controllers) that can be rendered in the view scripts.

Comment: You might, but you shouldn't. It kinda defeats the purpose of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning information to the view is the job of the controller, and doing what you're suggesting would muddy the boundaries of the MVC pattern.

What you should really be doing is assigning the model to the view (in the controller), and then access the various parts of the model within the view. Alternatively, you can assign only the relevant parts of the model in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that a model should indeed not be responsible for configuring the view, there are cases in which it is allowed (for instance the ViewModel pattern).
There are a couple of ways of retrieving or providing a view instance:

- Inject the view instance. From the controller you can provide the model the instance by injecting it (`$model->setView($this->view)`).
- Retrieve the view instance via the `ViewRenderer` helper: `$view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->view;`
- Retrieve the view instance via the Application bootstrapper: `$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->bootstrap('view')->getResource('view');`

Comment: Surely the idea of MVVM is still not to couple the View to the Model, but to go via the ViewModel as a data binding?